# VlookUp working with Numbers but Not Text

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have been using VLookUp for matching `numbers` I want trying to use it on `text` with `exact` match

When I do I get nothing, `no` matches at all even though there are matches present

```
Sub Match()

Dim I As Long, j As Long, cnt As Long
Dim lValue As Long
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet

Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

I = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For cnt = 2 To j
On Error Resume Next
lValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("A" & cnt), Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & I), 1, False)
If lValue <> 0 Then
    Sheet2.Range("C" & cnt).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Sheet2.Range("C" & cnt) = Sheet2.Range("A" & cnt).Value
End If
  lValue = 0
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `lValue ` should be a variant

Comment: @Davesexcel: That is a valid answer if you club it with an explanation. Comments are temporary. Your answer may help future visitors :)

Comment: That did it, yes please make it a proper answer so I can select it, `thank you`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change lValue  to a variant

```
Dim lValue As variant
```